kcfinder HTTP Error 500 on WordPress
I an getting an HTTP Error 500 when trying to use CiviEvent Event Name Badge Layouts and clicking on "Image (top left)" or "Image (top right)" fields, and after more investigation a similar problem editing a Message Template, choosing the HTML Editor Image Button and then clicking the Browse Server button in the Image Properties dialog
My guess is that it's a misconfiguration, but I can't work out what it would be.
Does anyone have any suggestions?
These are the two URLs that are failing:
https://mysite.org.au/app/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/packages/kcfinder/browse.php?cms=civicrm&type=images
https://mysite.org.au/app/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/packages/kcfinder/browse.php?cms=civicrm&type=images&CKEditor=msg_html&CKEditorFuncNum=0&langCode=en-au
I'm running:

CiviCRM 5.76.2
WordPress 6.6.1
PHP 8.1

My path settings are:

[cms.root]    https://mysite.org.au
[civicrm.root]    https://mysite.org.au/app/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/
[civicrm.files]   https://mysite.org.au/app/uploads/civicrm/
CiviCRM Resource URL: [civicrm.root]/
Image Upload URL: [civicrm.files]/persist/contribute/

The path to the Image Upload URL (public_html/app/uploads/civicrm/persist/contribute) has permissions: 0755
kcfinder is installed in: public_html/app/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/packages/kcfinder
